# controller method which returns LINQ query result

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a method which will return `LINQ` query result. I am creating this as separate method because multiple views will need the same query. But I do not know how to create the method with such return type.

```
public return_type GetData_ById(int? id) // what will be the return type?
        {
            var student_ = (from z in db.StudModels where z.Status == 10 select z).OrderByDescending(z => z.StudId).ToList();
            return student_;
        }
        
        public ActionResult CreateCard(int? id)
        {
            GetData_ById(id);
            return View(student_data);
        }
```

What will be the return type of the method `GetData_ById` and then how to call the function from  `CreateCard` method?

Comment: If you hover with the mouse on the `student` variable name then Visual Studio will show you the type.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a LINQ on the StudModels so problaly the return type is a list of StudModels:

```
List<StudModelsType>
```

The calling function would look like this:

```
List<StudModelsType> student_data = GetData_ById(id);
return View(student_data);
```